# Have I used LUKS properly?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, luks

I am about to go travelling to some high risk countries where corrupt officials will most likely try to go through my laptop and external HDD.

I am using Linux Mint and LUKS. Could someone please tell me based on these pictures whether I have encrypted them both properly, this includes the cache (or whatever it is called) as I would hate to leak information. I know that /boot can stay unencrypted.

**Picture of my laptop's HDD:**
[image: Internal pic]

**Picture of external HDD after I entered password:**
[image: External pic]

I can provide more information upon request.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably instead just leave the data you care about at home and install a fresh copy of whatever OS you're using before and after the trip.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell. We don't know what cipher, mode, or hash you are using, or your PBKDF2 iteration count.

Comment: @user I know but the country I am going to have poor internet, furthermore I need those files for my job.

Comment: @forest How do I provide that information?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, your LUKS setup is OK:

- On internal drive, you only have `/boot` that is unciphered. The rest of the volume consists in a stack of LUKS + LVM, so it's ok.
- On external drive, everything looks encrypted.

Just a small remark: 700MiB is a lot for a `/boot` partition....

Comment: I don't think 700 MiB is _necessarily_ a lot for the boot partition, depending on your setup. If you keep old kernels and have a bloated initramfs, you can quickly start using up quite a bit of storage.

Comment: Usually, one only keep the n and n-1 kernel.... keep every old kernel is a bit useless.... Nevertheless, every body is free to do what he want with his /boot partition :)

Comment: For people who compile their own kernels, keeping old ones can be _very_ useful for tracking down bugs.

Comment: False. Only the `.config` is needed for this purpose. Eventually the patches applied or the whole kernel source tree (wich already contains the binary) can be usefull ... but this is usually stored under /usr/src. A standalone kernel binary would be very painful for debugging...

Comment: Well you need the config as well as any seed files (e.g. for RANDSTRUCT), and that's only if you're doing a deterministic build. If you aren't, then things like compiler version can affect the resulting binary. I've had kernel bugs caused by compiler bugs that would not have been reproducible if I didn't have the original binary (unless I also kept track of the compiler version, its libraries, etc).

Comment: It's what Linux Mint did by default, perhaps because I enabled an option called role-back (I think) in case a mistake happens during an update.